# Is any way to communicate to MAAS360 from service

Tags: ios, mdm

We have MAAS360 MDM installed on every IPhones within the company. I would like to write a service which would ask status info about the phone from MAAS360 like "is location service on/off"...etc. We can check these manually but we have lots of phones so I want to automate this process.
Is there any API to communicate to MAAS360? 
Or can I send silent push notification to get info back from it? 
If so, I am looking for some documentation about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MaaS360 has web service APIs for a lot of stuff... didn't check for your specific needs, but...

In order to write a client app to make their API calls, they have to provision it for you and give you all the details.

To get that set up, I just called their tech support number and they took care of it very quickly...

For the API calls, you'll need:

- App Name
- App ID
- App Version numbe
- Platform
- Access Key
- Server

Also, they can send you a PDF of their current documentation (I'd share a link, but they sent me an attachment and I don't want to upload their docs).